# How to make the same JTextField input show in 2 separate class instances (JFrame windows)?

Tags: java, swing

I was told by my professor that we have to make a chat system using java swing. Now he made one before class, and it was very simple looking, nothing fancy. No servers.
In his main function, i had enough time to write what seemed very simple:

```
     ChatFrame Rick = new ChatFrame("Rick");
     ChatFrame Morty = new ChatFrame("Morty");

     Rick.receiver = Morty;
     Morty.receiver = Rick;
```

When he ran the program, 2 windows popped up, each of which you could type, and if you typed on "Ricks'" window a message and pressed send, it popped up in both windows. Of course, in Rick's window it was displayed as:

```
Me: (message sent)
```

and in Morty's window it was displayed as:

```
Rick: (message sent)
```

I was simply hoping for a little guidance on how this is being done... I can't find a clue on how he linked both of these windows to work together like that. If anyone could guide me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!
Thank you!

Currently I have made it so that I can chat with myself, I'm stuck wondering how to link the windows together.

currently i have 2 classes, one where I create the window, and the main class.

Main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class serverDriver 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         chatFrame alec = new chatFrame("Alec");
         chatFrame you = new chatFrame("You");

         alec.receiver = you;
         you.receiver = alec;
    }
}
```

Other Class:

```
    public class chatFrame extends JFrame 
    {
        private JButton sendB = new JButton("Send");
        private JTextField areaI;
        private JTextArea areaO = new JTextArea();
        private String user;
        public chatFrame receiver;

        public chatFrame(String name)
        {
            // Used to display name of the person sending code
            user = name;

            // Make and add text field for input, area for output, and button
            areaI = new JTextField(25);
            areaI.setBounds(35, 350, 350, 80);
            areaI.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 15));

            areaO.setBounds(35, 25, 350, 300);
            areaO.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 15));
            areaO.setEditable(false);
            areaO.setLineWrap(true);
            areaO.setWrapStyleWord(true);

            sendB.setBounds(390, 350, 88, 80);

            add(areaI); 
            add(sendB);
            add(areaO);

            // Set the dimensions of the frame, and make it visible
            setSize(500,500);  
            setLayout(null);  
            setVisible(true); 
            setTitle(name);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            theHandler handler = new theHandler();
            areaI.addActionListener(handler);
            sendB.addActionListener(handler);

        }
        private class theHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                 // Source where it happens, if event happens in each field such as click or enter
                if(event.getSource() == areaI || event.getSource() == sendB)
                {
                    // This will make the area receive the input
                    areaO.append(user + ": " + areaI.getText() + "\n");
                    // This will clear out the text field.
                    areaI.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm just really confused on how to make it so that I can view the message I send on both of the windows... Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to pass information back to `receiver`, this would mean that `receiver` will need some method that can be called which will allow the text to passed to the other window

Comment: @MadProgrammer So like a getMethod that gets the text of the input? I'm confused as to how I can pass the text to another window? Sorry..

Comment: More like a newMessage method, which the frame which generates the message would caller on the reviver

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just added this line: inside the actionPerformed method:
        receiver.areaO.append(getTitle() + ": " + areaI.getText() + "\n");

It seems to be working, i can now see the text in both windows. I didn't use a method, is this bad "programming"?